# Bundler not able to use gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, ruby-on-rails-5.1, react-rails

This is what is currently in my terminal. After Successfully setting up a rails app and making sure it worked. I set up the gem react-rails in my gem file. Then committed everything and from there I ran bundle install. Then I got an error stating that it could not find the babel-source-5.8.35 in any of the sources. but clearly its in my bundle ENV

```
➜  calendaract git:(master) bundle install
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.9.5
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.2
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.3
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.1.5
Using rack 2.0.4
Using rack-test 0.8.3
Using actionpack 5.1.5
Using nio4r 2.3.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.5
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.1.5
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 5.1.5
Using activemodel 5.1.5
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.5
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
***Using babel-source 5.8.35***
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using babel-transpiler 0.7.0
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using byebug 10.0.1
Using xpath 3.0.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using ffi 1.9.23
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.1.5
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using connection_pool 2.2.1
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3 
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using pg 1.0.0
Using puma 3.11.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.1.5
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using react-rails 2.4.4
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 3.11.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
Using turbolinks 5.1.0
Using uglifier 4.1.8
Using web-console 3.5.1
Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 74 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

➜  calendaract git:(master) rails g react:install
Could not find babel-source-5.8.35 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I Run bundle install, and clearly see my gem available locally all my paths and shims are set correctly. But when I run the generate script i get cannot find babel-source 5.8.35 and would love some help on what to do to be able to run?

```
rails generate react:install
```

Comment: do you have gem `webpacker` in your gem list ? just make sure you followed all steps in this docs [react-rail](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails).

Comment: yes, I do now and also did the first installation for webpacker and got the same issue

Comment: try add `babel-source` inside your gemfile just above `react-rails` of try installing that gem manually `gem install babel-source` and try bundle install again

Answer (score 0):

It seems when you trying to do bundle install dependency for `react-rails` is missing so you need to either add `babel-source` to the **Gemfile** file list or install manually.

before starting check if that gem exist in your gem list:

```
gem list|grep babel-source # grep for ubuntu users you can use other alternative for other OS
```

and check whether it showing that gem and it is returning correct version or not else retry bundle install again as follows:

At first i suggest you to follow [react github](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) doc just make sure you haven't missed anything from it. if you still facing problem after that try adding that **dependency gem** as follows:

inside your Gemfile you can add this just above `react-rails` so that it meets the dependency when it tries to install. just make sure to remove Gemfile.lock so that it will be fresh installation.

```
gem 'babel-source', '~> 5.8.35'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

check whether your log and confirm your facing that error again or not if your facing again try manually you can run this in terminal:

```
gem install babel-source -v 5.8.35
```

then

```
bundle install
```

if it is successful run `generate` command for **React**.

*all the above commands are debugging process since i cannot add much details into the comment option i'm posting it here so please let me know the results of it*